# Find Indexes that Maps a Numpy Array to Another

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, search

If we have an numpy array `a` that needs to be sampled with replacement to create a second numpy array `b`,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10, 200*1000)
b = np.random.choice(a, len(a), replace=True)
```

What is the most efficient way to find an array of indexes named `mapping` that will transform `a` to `b`? It is OK to change `np.random.choice` to a more suitable function.

The following code is too slow and takes 7-8 seconds on a Macbook Pro to creating the `mapping` array. With an array size of 1 million, it will take much longer.

```
mapping = np.array([], dtype=np.int)
for n in b:
    m = np.searchsorted(a, n)
    mapping = np.append(mapping, m)
```

Comment: Just tried it with the software package numba, I was able to minimize the runtime 3 to 4 seconds on average. Unfortunately, the numpy append is very inefficient, whereas the append of lists is much faster.

Comment: Both `np.searchsorted()` and `np.append()` are substitutes for some looping actions. It should, indeed, to be a pain in performance if they are performed on every iteration instead of that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, run the choice on index of `a` and slice `a` using this random index `mapping`:

```
mapping = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(a)), len(a), replace=True)
b = a[mapping]
```

Comment: Wow, your code took 0.004 secs to run on my laptop!